# How to add a submenu item to a popup menu item in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to add a few submenu items to an existing popup menu item. I found several examples on how to create a submenu for a standard menu, but none about creating a submenu for a popup menu.

I tried to apply to the popup menu the same logic as for a standard menu, but failed to do that properly (while at the same time I have no trouble in creating a standard menu with submenus).

In a portion of code like the one below, how to add a submenu ?

```
# ...

class ButtonContext(wx.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonContext, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
 
        button_popup = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'test popup')
        self.Append(button_popup)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.button_action, button_popup)
 
    def button_action(self, event):
        event.Skip()

# ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, in fact popup menus are based on `wx.Menu` class so the logic and the behaviour are the same

```
class ButtonContext(wx.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonContext, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        button_popup = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'test popup')
        submenu_popup = wx.Menu()
        submenu_button_popup = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'test submenu popup')
        submenu_popup.Append(submenu_button_popup)
        self.AppendSubMenu(submenu_popup, "submenu")
        self.Append(button_popup)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.button_action, button_popup)
```

Comment: Well, it can be said to work this way, but not exactly like I imagined. The code 'as is' gives ```Menu.AppendSubMenu(): not enough arguments``` error, which can be solved by adding a text label as per https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Menu.html#wx.Menu.AppendSubMenu; however, this also means a new menu item is created for that text label (on which the submenu is tied). Should I understand that this is the only way to do it ? I was interested in keeping the 'original' menu item, as in my real code that one also has a bitmap icon associated with it (but not a catastrophic issue if otherwise, though).

Comment: sorry i forgotted it, now i edited, it should works, and yes, the only way to use submenus is to append a wx.Menu as item of a menu wiht AppendSubMenu()

Comment: There is also `SetSubMenu(menu)` for a menu that has been defined separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate the `SetSubMenu(menu)` method which can also be used to create a sub-menu in this instance.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.SetTitle("test frame")

        sizer_0 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.window_1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.window_1.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)
        sizer_0.Add(self.window_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.button = wx.Button(self.pane_2, wx.ID_ANY, "test button")
        sizer_2.Add(self.button, 0, 0, 0)

        self.pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.pane_2.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.window_1.SplitVertically(self.pane_1, self.pane_2)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_0)
        self.Layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnButtonContextMenu, self.button)
        self.Show()

    def OnButtonContextMenu(self, event):
        self.PopupMenu(ButtonContext(self))

class ButtonContext(wx.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonContext, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
 
        button_popup = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'test popup')
        self.Append(button_popup)        
        submenu = wx.Menu()
        submenu1 = wx.MenuItem(submenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Submenu 1')
        submenu2 = wx.MenuItem(submenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Submenu 2')
        submenu3 = wx.MenuItem(submenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Submenu 3')
        submenu.Append(submenu1)
        submenu.Append(submenu2)
        submenu.Append(submenu3)
        button_popup2 = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'A sub menu')
        button_popup2.SetSubMenu(submenu)
        self.Append(button_popup2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.button_action, button_popup)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.submenu1_action, submenu1)
 
    def button_action(self, event):
        print("Test Menu Button")
        event.Skip()

    def submenu1_action(self, event):
        print("Submenu 1")
        event.Skip()
        
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]